# Go to directory of symlink file target

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, path, symbolic-link

How can I create a command (or alias) to go to the directory which contains the target file of a symlink.  For example, if I have a symlink

```
symFile@ -> /Users/zhermes/some/dir/someFile
```

I'd like to be able to run `<command> symFile` and have it `cd` me to `/Users/zhermes/some/dir/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function checks whether the symlink exists and `cd`s to its parent directory. Of course, it also works with regular files. It could be more clever with errors from `readlink` or `cd`, but it's a start.

#### GNU/Linux:

In GNU/Linux, you can use `readlink -f`:

```
cdln() { [[ -f $1 ]] && cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$1")")" || echo "No such file: $1" }
```

#### BSD / OS X:

The following should work on Unix / OS X, where there's no `-f` option to `readlink`. Of course this means it will not follow nested symlinks.

```bsh
cdln() { [[ -f $1 ]] && cd "$(dirname "$(readlink "$1")")" || echo "No such file: $1" }
```

On OS X, you can install `coreutils` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and use `greadlink -f` instead.

Comment: Awesome.  This works after removing the `-f` option from `readlink` which doesn't seem to be supported in the OSX version (despite appearing in the `man` page).

Comment: Ah, but it means something different there. I updated the answer. You can get GNU `readlink` with Homebrew if you want the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I just got `greadlink` via `coreutils` which is available on both macports or homebrew!